# Div is taking a extra space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Hi I have a div inside it there is a svg.i tried ti figur out using firebug but havent sound any solution of why div is taking the extra space rather than the height of the svg.

Please have look on to the screen shots.

firefox:

div height width
[image]

svg height width

[image]

Now have a look at the chrome screen shots

div
[image]

svg
[image]

i am a little bit new so i am not understanding how to solve this

Comment: Try using a Reset CSS stylesheet  - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ - different browser(s) have different default padding and margins.

Comment: @Sunil Kumar give me demo link

Comment: @Nathan Srivi  please have a look at http://119.82.65.220/yourmap

Comment: @Sunil Kumar ok please wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert the css into map id

if you able to modify map div simply use inline style

```
element.style {
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   height: 615px !important;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

else create internal css

```
#map{
clear: both !important;
   display: block !important;
   height: 615px !important;
   overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add the doc type.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Isn't the doctype of the svg generated if there is otherwise not one set..? In Chrome it does anyways..

Answer (score 0):

For my knoladge, the SVG iks still a "hack" with browsers. It tends to ignore your width and height parametres. We have similar issues on our page (mybbeye.com). We were unable to resolve it, so I would recomend just to transform your SVG graphics in a png image. With that, at least you can have a total control of width and heigth.

Also if your SVG is from apple KeyNote, note that this software is bad : it adds font and size class for every letter

Was meant as comment :)